# Postgres: How do you create a USER MAPPING for a user whose name includes a period character ('.')

Tags: postgresql, foreign-data-wrapper

Postgresql 9.6:

Trying to run this SQL:

```
CREATE USER MAPPING FOR wes.gamble
            SERVER fdw_server
            OPTIONS (user 'username', password 'password')
```

It fails because of the period. But 'wes.gamble' is a valid Postgres user.

I tried escaping the period with a backslash (wes.gamble).

I tried using single quotes ('wes.gamble').

I cannot get this CREATE USER MAPPING command to run with any name that contains a period.

Any ideas on how I can get such a command to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a quoted identifier. In this particular case `"wes.gamble"` should do the job (note double quotes).

[Here's](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) some more information about identifiers in PostgreSQL documentation.

Comment: I could swear I read somewhere that single quotes were preferred and so I was eschewing double quotes. Doh! Thanks @Tupteq